# Select clients that ordered only specific conferences and none else

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, relational-division

Imagine we have a client table and an order table, which are linked together like this: client.id = order.client_id. Order table entry contains a product id that has been purchased. Product table entry contains a conference id from which this product has been purchased.
How do I select clients that have only purchased products from a list of specific conferences?

I could solve this with a PHP script, making multiple requests, rearranging data but that is no fun.

I tried this so far:

```
select
    o.client_id,
    array_agg(p.conference_id) as conference_ids
from product as p
left join order as o
    on o.id = p.order_id
where
    p.conference_id = any('{ 46545, 46543 }'::int[])
```

But this didn't work as it selects clients that have purchased not only from these but from other conferences, too.

Edit: fixed sql to be syntactically correct

Comment: `client.id` is not defined.

Comment: that isn't really the point but I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this without using arrays would be:

```
select client.id
from product as p
left join order as o on o.id = p.order_id
group by client.id
having count(*) filter(where p.conference_id not in (46545, 46543)) = 0;
```

If you also wanted to assert that *both* of the above two conferences were also attended (i.e. attended both, but no others), you could add another assertion to the `HAVING` clause:

```
select client.id
from product as p
left join order as o on o.id = p.order_id
group by client.id
having count(*) filter(where p.conference_id not in (46545, 46543)) = 0 and
       min(p.conference_id) <> max(p.conference_id);
```

Comment: `client.id` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause.

Your query references table `client`, which you do not select - that's a syntax error. You can get the `client_id` directly from the orders table instead.

```
select o.client_id, array_agg(p.conference_id) as conference_ids
from orders as o 
inner join product as p on p.product_id = o.id
group by o.client_id
having count(*) filter(where not p.conference_id = any('{ 46545, 46543 }'::int[])) = 0
```

Note that `order` is a language keyword, hence a poor choice for a table name; I renamed it to `orders` instead.

If you want to ensure that the client placed orders for all conferences that are listed in the array, you can add another condition to the `having` clause; you can make this independent of the number of elements of the arrays with `array_length()`:

```
having 
    count(distinct p.conference_id) 
        filter(where p.conference_id = any('{ 46545, 46543 }'::int[])) = array_length('{ 46545, 46543 }'::int[], 1)
    and count(*) filter(where not p.conference_id = any('{ 46545, 46543 }'::int[])) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a clients table.  One fun method uses set operation:

```
select c.id
from clients c
except
select o.client_id
from orders o join
     products p
     on o.id = p.order_id
where p.conference_id not in (46545, 46543);
```

Actually, I sort of prefer the aggregation methods -- they are more versatile.  But the query in your question is syntactically incorrect and I have the feeling you would like to use the `clients` table.

Comment: sorry, this didn't work, it just gave me the whole client table back

Comment: @SaveMyGrave . . . Can you set up a db/sql fiddle?  Are you sure you are only selecting one column in each subquery?

Comment: @SaveMyGrave . . .  Except that Tim's answer (like your original query) has an invalid column reference.  With that fix, both Tim's and GMB's answer should work -- as should this one.

Comment: column references and "slightly" invalid syntax is not a concern, pgAdmin highlights all of that, so that's not really the point; the logic behind the problem solved prevails